# if $ a_{n+1}=n^2+3\sqrt{\frac{3a_{n}-a_{n-1}}{2}}$ this sequence have infinite number of "good" term

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory

**Question:**

> Given a sequence $\{a_{n}\}$, call a term $a_{k}$ "good", if there exist $a_{m},a_{n}$, such that $$a_{k}=a_{m}a_{n}$$($a_{m}$ and $a_{n}$ are allowed to be equal.)
>   Otherwise it is called a "bad" term.
>
> Now give the sequence $\{a_{n}\}$ with such 
>   $$\begin{align}
> a_{1}&=3\\
> a_{2}&=7\\
> a_{n+1}&=n^2+3\sqrt{\dfrac{3a_{n}-a_{n-1}}{2}},\quad n\ge 2\end{align}$$
>   show that: this sequence  has an infinite number of "good" terms and has an infinite number of bad" terms.

Now 
I have use induction methods to prove

$$a_{n}=n^2+n+1$$
(can you someone sovle it without the induction?)

Note 
$$n^4+n^2+1=(n^2+n+1)[(n-1)^2+(n-1)+1]$$
so this sequence have infinite number of good term,

and Now I can't prove have infinite number of “bad" term? Thank you

Comment: everyone understand my problem?

Comment: A good element of the sequence is a term that is the product of two other elements of the sequence, and a bad term is an element of the sequence that isn't?

Comment: It seems like you might be using $a$ to refer to two different sequences, and that part of your post is in the title but I'm not sure.

Comment: Yes,That's mean.

Comment: But, but... It was a respectful comment... (Maybe you wanted to say "That is what I meant")

Comment: I've tried to edit it to read better as a native English speaker. Would you confirm that I haven't changed the meaning?

Comment: the sequence starts with 3, 7, 13, 21, 31. That's based on wolfram alpha. It is indeed $x^2+x+1$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $p$ is a prime number dividing $a_n$ but not any $a_m$ for $m<n$ then $a_n$ is bad. Hence it is enough to show that infinitely many prime numbers divide some entry of your sequence.

This can be done by a standard trick: Suppose there are finitely many primes that divide the entries of this sequence, let $N$ be their product.  Then $a_N = N^2+N+1$ is not divisible by any of these primes, contradicting the assumption.

Comment: Nice.  Such a_n are super-bad, they are not a product of $k$  terms of the sequence for any $k \geq 2$.

Comment: I don't understand you methods, and I fell you not understand my problem

Comment: Your definition of a "bad" number in this sequence to be one that is not a product of two earlier terms. So for a number in this sequence to be bad it is sufficient (albeit not necessary) for it to have a prime divisor that no other term before it has.  What I showed is that there are infinitely many primes that divide some number in this sequence, for each such prime we just look at the first time it divides a number in your sequence, this must be a bad term.

Answer (score 1):

An increasing sequence of integers with a bounded number of prime divisors has at most $A(\log n)^b$ terms less than $n$, for all $n>1$ and suitable constants $A$ and $b$ .   Sequences with polynomial rate of increase are too slow to meet that condition, and have infinitely many prime divisors.

As explained in the first answer, having an infinite set of prime divisors of the sequence means that there are infinitely many "bad" elements of the sequence that are not the product of earlier terms in the sequence. Thus,

> any sequence with polynomial rate of growth, such as $a_n = n^2 = n + 1$, increases too slowly to have only finite number of "bad" terms.

The point of these observations is that no clever Euclid-style argument is necessary, only the rate of increase of the sequence and counting arguments about solutions of $\prod p_i^{e_i} \leq n$.

In the other direction, proving that a sequence has infinitely many "good" terms (in addition to the infinitely many bad terms), seems to require algebraic structure.

Answer (score 1):

It is fairly evident that $a_{n} = n^{2} + n + 1$ satisfies the equation, $n \geq 2$,
\begin{align}
a_{n+1}=n^2+3\sqrt{\frac{3a_{n}-a_{n-1}}{2}}
\end{align}
where $a_{1}=3$ and $a_{2}=7$. Now define a "good" product as $a_{k} = a_{n} \cdot a_{m}$ and a "bad" product as $a_{s} \neq a_{p} \cdot a_{q}$. It is clear that if $n$ and $m$ differ by $1$ then the "good" product is obtained, ie $a_{n^{2}} = a_{n} \cdot a_{n-1}$. Since $n \in N^{0}$ then there are infinitely many many "good" products. Alternatively, for an example, consider $a_{n} \cdot a_{n-3}$ which is 
\begin{align}
a_{n} \cdot a_{n-3} = (n-1)^{4} - 3(n-1)^{2}-4(n-1)+5
\end{align}
and is not of the form $a_{k}$ for any value of $n$. Consider $a_{n+2} \cdot a_{n-3} = n^{4} - 11 n^{2} + 49$ which is also not of the form $a_{k}$. By the same process as before there are an infinitely many number of products that do not produce the same polynomial field.

Comment: "infinitely many products $a_i a_j$ are not in the sequence" is different from the target of the question, "infinitely many $a_n$ are not equal to any product $a_i a_j$".